# What is shutdown monitor on my lg3

Tags: rooting

My wife has an lg3. When I search our history on google search it say stuff like com.lge.shutdownmonitor what is she doing and what does this mean.

Comment: Where are you searching your google history to see this?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a test application. Anything as *com.lge*.*** will be there by the manufacturer LG. There are often several test and debug applications that are included in the OS, but are normally hidden to the user.